# Load video src with data-attribute while using video.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I'm trying to add videos only on hover or tap so that they don't preload. So, I'm using data-trailer-src to add the video source when needed. But I'm getting these errors.

> video.min.js:12 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media.

I'm using the video.js. Here is the [live site](https://drougnov.github.io/Dashboard/video.html) if you want to check. The first video doesn't have src, the second one does.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");

                columns.forEach((column) => {
                    const thumbnail = column.querySelector(".thumbnail");
                    const videoContainer =
                        column.querySelector(".video-container");
                    const video = videoContainer.querySelector("video");
                    let player;

                    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                        videoContainer.style.display = "none";
                    });

                    // Mouse Events (Desktop)
                    column.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);
                    column.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);

                    // Touch Events (Mobile)
                    let touchStart = null;
                    column.addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
                    column.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);

                    // Video player setup
                    player = videojs(video, {
                        autoplay: false,
                        muted: true,
                        loop: true,
                    });

                    // Handle click event outside video container
                    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

                    // Handle click event on column
                    if (window.matchMedia("(hover: hover)").matches) {
                        column.addEventListener("click", handleClickInside);
                    } else if (window.matchMedia("(hover: none)").matches) {
                        column.addEventListener(
                            "touchstart",
                            handleClickInside
                        );
                    }

                    // Handle mouse enter event
                    function handleMouseEnter() {
                        if (!player.paused()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        loadVideo();
                        thumbnail.style.opacity = "0";
                        videoContainer.style.display = "block";
                        player.play();
                    }

                    // Handle mouse leave event
                    function handleMouseLeave() {
                        thumbnail.style.opacity = "1";
                        player.pause();
                        player.currentTime(0);
                        videoContainer.style.display = "none";
                    }

                    // Handle touch start event
                    function handleTouchStart(event) {
                        loadVideo();
                        touchStart = event.changedTouches[0].identifier;
                    }

                    // Handle touch end event
                    function handleTouchEnd(event) {
                        const touchEnd = event.changedTouches[0].identifier;

                        if (
                            touchStart !== touchEnd &&
                            !event.target.classList.contains("vjs-control")
                        ) {
                            // Touch outside of the container, reset video
                            player.pause();
                            player.currentTime(0);
                            videoContainer.style.display = "none";
                        } else if (
                            !player.paused() &&
                            event.target.classList.contains("vjs-control")
                        ) {
                            // Prevent resetting when interacting with video controls
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        } else {
                            // Touch inside the container, start playing the video
                            if (!player.paused()) {
                                return;
                            }
                            thumbnail.style.opacity = "0";
                            videoContainer.style.display = "block";
                            player.play();
                        }
                    }

                    // Handle click event outside video container
                    function handleClickOutside(event) {
                        const isClickInsideVideoContainer =
                            event.target.closest(".video-container");
                        const videoContainers =
                            document.querySelectorAll(".video-container");

                        if (!isClickInsideVideoContainer) {
                            videoContainers.forEach((container) => {
                                const video = container.querySelector("video");
                                const thumbnail =
                                    container.parentElement.querySelector(
                                        ".thumbnail"
                                    );
                                const player = videojs(video);

                                thumbnail.style.opacity = "1";
                                player.pause();
                                player.currentTime(0);
                                container.style.display = "none";
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    // Handle click event inside column
                    function handleClickInside() {
                        if (!video.paused) {
                            handleClick();
                        }
                    }

                    // Custom click handler
                    function handleClick() {
                        alert("Hi!");
                    }

                    // Load video source if data-trailer-src is set
                    function loadVideo() {
                        const dataSrc = video.getAttribute("data-trailer-src");
                        if (dataSrc) {
                            video.setAttribute("src", dataSrc);
                            video.removeAttribute("data-trailer-src");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
.container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
            gap: 5rem;
        }
        .column {
            position: relative;
        }
        .thumbnail {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .thumbnail img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .video-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .video-container video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        @media (max-width: 650px) {
            .container {
                grid-template-columns: auto;
            }
        }
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1684482570533-b97679dd0705?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4fHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video>
                        <source
                            class="video-js"
                            data-trailer-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/431680358.sd.mp4?s=3f97b05e5d5dab21298a96bb5653849567aaf675&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                            type="video/mp4"
                        />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685796766-0fddd3e480de?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzNnx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video>
                        <source
                            class="video-js"
                            src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/503759306.sd.mp4?s=273116dd8b495498766d3fe03e8416fff0cc68b5&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                            data-trailer-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/503759306.sd.mp4?s=273116dd8b495498766d3fe03e8416fff0cc68b5&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                            type="video/mp4"
                        />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```